# Socket client repeatedly wait for server in connect c++

Tags: c++, sockets, client-server

I would like to ask, how to make socket client repeatedly waiting for server. For example if socket server is not running, then client is waiting about 1-3 seconds during connect() and then throw error 10038 (WSAENOTSOCK). If server is ready, then it connects.

I want the client wait if server is unreachable. Is there any flag for this? I tried to put connect() into while() loop but it was not useful.

Here is the important fromcode

```
#define SOCKET_DEFAULT_PROTOCOL SOCK_STREAM

    typedef struct dev_socket {
        std::string ip = "";
        std::thread openner;
        unsigned short port = 0;
        SOCKET num = 0, external_num = 0;
    }dev_socket;
    
    int openClientSocket(dev_socket &io, std::string server_ipv4, unsigned short port) {
        char *server_name = (server_ipv4.empty() ? localhost_addr : const_cast<char*>(server_ipv4.c_str()));
        int retval, socket_type = SOCKET_DEFAULT_PROTOCOL;
        struct sockaddr_in server;
        struct hostent *hp;
    #if defined(_WIN32)
        int fromlen;
    #else
        socklen_t fromlen;
    #endif
    
    #if defined(_WIN32)
        WSADATA wsaData;
        if ((retval = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &wsaData)) != 0) {
            cout << "ERROR! Client: WSAStartup() failed (socket number " + std::to_string(io.num) +
                ") with error " + std::to_string(retval) + ".\n";
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }
    #endif
    
        // Attempt to detect if we should call gethostbyname() or gethostbyaddr()
        hp = gethostbyname(server_name);
        if (hp == NULL) {
            cout << "ERROR! Client: Cannot resolve address \"" + (std::string)(server_name) + "\": Error.\n";
            cleenup();
            return 1;
        }
    
        //Creating SOCKET
        // Copy the resolved information into the sockaddr_in structure
        memset(&server, 0, sizeof(server));
        memcpy(&(server.sin_addr), hp->h_addr, hp->h_length);
        server.sin_family = hp->h_addrtype;
        server.sin_port = htons(port);
        io.num = socket(AF_INET, socket_type, 0); /* Open a socket */
        if (io.num < 0) {
            cout << "ERROR! Client: Error Opening socket number " + std::to_string(io.num) + ". " + getSocketErrorOrNewLine();
            cleenup();
            return 1;
        }
    
        //CONNECTing
        if ((connect(io.num, (struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server))) == -1) {
            cout << "ERROR! Client: connect() failed (socket number " + std::to_string(io.num) + "). " + getSocketErrorOrNewLine();
            cleenup();
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

Thank you in advance for your answers.

**UPDATE:** The while() loop is working (but probably not best) solution - there was bug in testing api.

Comment: *I tried to put connect() into while() loop but it was not useful.* Please show your attempt.

Comment: while (io.num != 0) {
  if ((ret = connect(io.num, (struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server))) == -1) {
   cout << "WARN! Server is not responding. Repeating.\n";
  }
 }

Comment: Does cout print the message? What happens when the server comes online?

Comment: I was wrong, the while cycle  is working.

Comment: But it seems more like a workaround then good solution. Do you know how to make it with some flag?

Comment: Are you asking for some boolean flag in the socket API? Or are you asking for introducing some user-defined flag?

Comment: There is no flag to automatically retry `connect()`, until either the connection succeeds or until the heat death of the universe.

Comment: Something like ioctlsocket(sock, FIONBIO, &nonblocking_long) - for switching blocking/non-blocking accept()/connect(). I think that this must be solved by winsock2 developers properly.

Comment: Sam Varshavchik - Yep, very funny. But I would appreciate if connect() would wait "until the heat death of the universe". But it waits approx. 3 seconds.

Comment: Waiting a little while and then trying the `connect()` call again is the only solution to the server-not-there-yet problem that I'm aware of.

Comment: There is no way to make `connect()` wait/retry until a connection is open. Putting the socket into non-blocking mode won't fix that. Either the server is available or it is not. A loop is required (with a short delay in between iterations) if you must wait. However, note that on Windows, you can reuse the same socket for multiple `connect()` calls in a loop, but on most other platforms if `connect()` fails then the socket state is unspecified so you need to close the socket and create a new socket before calling `connect()` again. This is stated as much in the Windows and Linux documentations.

Comment: WSAENOTSOCK can't be caused by just a failed connection. WSAENOTSOCK means **you** closed the socket and then you tried to use it again. That's on you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As many of you wrote, the while cycle is the only way. I hoped that there is some "pretty" solution, but this is also fine.